# Duplicated off-topic close reason

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration, off-topic

When clicking "Close" -> "off-topic because...", the 1<sup>st</sup> option is

> Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Here, if we select the 6<sup>th</sup> option,

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Then the 2<sup>nd</sup> option in the next window is "belongs on superuser.com".

Aren't they redundant? If not, when to select the previous one, and when to select the later one? It is not easy to make the correct selection since the difference is not that obvious.

Comment: Generally the question as to if the question is terrible can make that distinction. Also that reason can be used even if it wouldn't be a good fit for SuperUser as it only proposes it as a possibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first option is to vote to *close* the question. If closed, the question will remain on Stack Overflow with an "on hold" (and later a "closed") indicator. The second option, however, is to vote to *migrate* the question to the site you've selected from the list.

Not all questions about general computing hardware and software are good enough to migrate to Super User, which is why the first option exist. Please only vote to migrate when the only problem with the question is that it was asked on the wrong site. If it has other problems, then it would be preferable if it was closed here, there's absolutely no reason to offload sub-par questions to other sites.